# Vue router no funciona en producción

Tags: html, vue.js, web, vue-router

Tengo un sitio hecho en Vue y vue-router, cuando lo subo a producción funciona bien el redireccionamiento pero cuando recargo la pagina en cualquier ruta me aparece **error 404**.

Espero me puedan ayudar

Saludos

Comment: ¿Qué servidor usas para manejar las peticiones HTTP?

Comment: Hola! Gracias por contestar, uso Hostgator

Comment: Me refiero a Nginx, Apache, IIS... Etc. Depende de tu software es como deberás configurar las peticiones para que se redirijan al archivo index.html